# How to clear only one index from ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried to remove only "Nokia" from ArrayList how to do it? But the rest should be printed!

```java
package arraylisthashmaphashlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arraylisthashmaphashlist {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList <String> mobiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    mobiles.add("Nokia");
    mobiles.add("Apple");
    mobiles.add("Samsung");
    mobiles.add("Oppo");
    System.out.println(mobiles);
    
    mobiles.clear();
    System.out.println(mobiles);
```

Comment: Use one of the remove() methods, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: When developing code you might want to have documentation at hand: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/index.html

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? `clear()` is, err, *clearly* specified to remove everything. If that's not what you want, don't use it.

Comment: Obligatory Streams usage: `mobiles.stream().filter(t -> !Objects.equals(t, "Nokia")).toList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mobiles.remove("Nokia")
```

or you can do `mobiles.remove(mobiles.indexOf("Nokia"))`, which will find the index of the first element equal to "Nokia" in your list, and then pass that to the remove function which can either remove an Object  by index or by the Object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```java
mobiles.remove("Nokia");
```

To your code before `mobiles.clear();`.